# Private App publishing to Google Play store

Tags: android

We have an organization account. I would like to upload a test apk and research what needs to be done to create a private app that is only for 1 or more organizations.

We may have multiple versions of the same app. How do we go about that.

There is no one to talk at with Google. It really is not helpful. I am trying to determinate the best approach for us and our app.

There are these different accounts I don't know which one is the right one.

1- developer
2- organization
3- android enterprise.

The app we are making is not for public use. It is only used for businesses. I am sure it is not the first time someone is doing this.

I wish there was some guidance as how you approach this.

If  found this: https://support.google.com/a/answer/2494992?hl=en

what is the difference between managed play services, admin console, google play console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you choose to use the Google Play Store to distribute an app for a closed group of users, then using Android Enterprise and "managed Google Play" is the only official way:

[Manage private apps](https://support.google.com/work/android/answer/9563481?hl=en&ref_topic=6145152)

Alternatively, you can use other providers like Visual Studio App center to distribute your apps. But all alternatives require your users to enable APK installations from unknown sources.

Answer (score 0):

I have an issue while trying to create a private app on Google Play store.

I created a new app as usual and followed instruction given by google [here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/work/answer/6145139#zippy=%2Cpublish-to-your-own-organization).

But when I try to create a Production (or Closed or Internal) release, the fields are disabled and I have a box saying "*Complete the steps above to continue with your release*"

I checked everything (notably in *App content* rubric) and I can not find what information is missing to let me upload my file.